I am trying to fit a mixed-effects model with a proportion as the response. I'm stumped on which distribution fits my model
Currently, this is my best-fit model. dHARMA does not look great. The response has many zeroes and many 1's
model_pollen_species.bi <- glmmTMB(proportion_sunflower ~ species + 
                    (1|farm) + (1|date) + (1|Bee.ID), 
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                    data = combined_pollen)
                             
diagnose(model_pollen_species.bi)

simulation.model_pollen_species.bi <- 
     simulateResiduals(fittedModel = model_pollen_species.bi)

plot(simulation.model_pollen_species.bi)

dHARMA residuals:


Hi @user412636, welcome to CV. It's very hard to diagnose and make suggestions about models, without knowing the context. What are you modelling? What are the covariates? What's your study design? :)
